# Oracle Lag function with dynamic parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I have a specific problem. I have a table which contains invalid values.
I need to replace the invalid values (here `0`) with the previous value which  is bigger than `0`.

The difficulty is, it is not appropiate for me to use an Update or an insert(Cursor and update would do it).Well my only way is to use a Select statement.

When I use the `lag(col1, 1)` - function with when case, I get only one column with the correct value.

```
select col1, col2 realcol2,  
(case 
  when col2 = 0 then 
    lag(col2,1,1) over (partition by col1 order by col1 )
  else
   col2
  end ) col2,     
col3 realcol3,
(case 
  when col3 = 0 then 
    lag(col3,1,1) over (partition by col1 order by col1 )
  else
   col3
  end ) col3
from test_table
```

Contents of `TEST_TABLE`:

```
---------------------------
 Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4
---------------------------
  A   |  0   |  1   |  5
  B   |  0   |  4   |  0
  C   |  2   |  0   |  0
  D   |  0   |  0   |  0
  E   |  3   |  5   |  0
  F   |  0   |  3   |  0
  G   |  0   |  3   |  1
  A   |  0   |  1   |  5
  E   |  3   |  5   |  0
```

Expected query result:

```
---------------------------
 Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4
---------------------------
  A   |  0   |  1   |  5
  B   |  0   |  4   |  5
  C   |  2   |  4   |  5
  D   |  2   |  4   |  5
  E   |  3   |  5   |  5
  F   |  3   |  3   |  5
  G   |  3   |  3   |  1
  A   |  3   |  1   |  5
  E   |  3   |  5   |  5
```

Comment: why is it not appropriate to use a cursor?  That would effective and efficient.

Comment: How is ordering defined in your data? I.e. why are there trailing `A` and `E` values for `Col1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT col1,
       CASE col2 WHEN 0 THEN NVL( LAG( CASE col2 WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE col2 END ) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( ORDER BY NULL ), 0 ) ELSE col2 END AS col2,
       CASE col3 WHEN 0 THEN NVL( LAG( CASE col3 WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE col3 END ) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( ORDER BY NULL ), 0 ) ELSE col3 END AS col3,
       CASE col4 WHEN 0 THEN NVL( LAG( CASE col4 WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE col4 END ) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( ORDER BY NULL ), 0 ) ELSE col4 END AS col4
FROM   table_name;
```

**Result**:

```
COL1       COL2       COL3       COL4
---- ---------- ---------- ----------
A             0          1          5 
B             0          4          5 
C             2          4          5 
D             2          4          5 
E             3          5          5 
F             3          3          5 
G             3          3          1 
A             3          1          5 
E             3          5          5
```

Answer (score 8):

I'm assuming an additional column `col0` that contains an obvious ordering criteria for your data, as your `col1` example data isn't really ordered correctly (repeated, trailing values of `A` and `E`).

I love the `MODEL` clause for these kinds of purposes. The following query yields the expected result:

```sql
WITH t(col0, col1, col2, col3, col4) AS (
  SELECT 1, 'A', 0, 1, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'B', 0, 4, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'C', 2, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'D', 0, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'E', 3, 5, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'F', 0, 3, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 'G', 0, 3, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 'A', 0, 1, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, 'E', 3, 5, 0 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT * FROM t
MODEL
  DIMENSION BY (row_number() OVER (ORDER BY col0) rn)
  MEASURES (col1, col2, col3, col4)
  RULES (
    col2[any] = DECODE(col2[cv(rn)], 0, NVL(col2[cv(rn) - 1], 0), col2[cv(rn)]),
    col3[any] = DECODE(col3[cv(rn)], 0, NVL(col3[cv(rn) - 1], 0), col3[cv(rn)]),
    col4[any] = DECODE(col4[cv(rn)], 0, NVL(col4[cv(rn) - 1], 0), col4[cv(rn)])
  )
```

Result:

```
RN   COL1  COL2  COL3  COL4
1    A     0     1     5
2    B     0     4     5
3    C     2     4     5
4    D     2     4     5
5    E     3     5     5
6    F     3     3     5
7    G     3     3     1
8    A     3     1     5
9    E     3     5     5
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7/6723)

#### A note on the MODEL clause vs. window function-based approaches

While the above looks cool (or scary, depending on your point of view), you should certainly prefer using a window function based appraoch as exposed by the other elegant answers by [nop77svk (using `LAST_VALUE() IGNORE NULLS`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34160956/521799) or [MT0 (using `LAG() IGNORE NULLS`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34163217/521799). [I've explained these answers more in detail in this blog post](http://blog.jooq.org/2015/12/17/how-to-fill-sparse-data-with-the-previous-non-empty-value-in-sql/).

Comment: @nop77svk: Yes. It's like a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet. As long as you don't produce cycles between cells in your rules, you're fine

Comment: Heh. Perhaps I should attempt to tackle this problem here with `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`, too, to make things even wilder? :)

Comment: You certainly should. :-)

Comment: @nop77svk: Technically, that's the same thing

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you want the *previous* values as per your *original data order* (whatever that might be), then your query **might** look like:

```
with preserve_the_order$ as (
    select X.*,
        rownum as original_order$
    from test_table X
)
select X.col1,
    nvl(last_value(case when col2 > 0 then col2 end) ignore nulls over (order by original_order$ rows between unbounded preceding and current row), col2) as col2,
    nvl(last_value(case when col3 > 0 then col3 end) ignore nulls over (order by original_order$ rows between unbounded preceding and current row), col3) as col3,
    nvl(last_value(case when col4 > 0 then col4 end) ignore nulls over (order by original_order$ rows between unbounded preceding and current row), col4) as col4
from preserve_the_order$ X
order by original_order$
;
```

Result:

```
COL1       COL2       COL3       COL4
---- ---------- ---------- ----------
A             0          1          5
B             0          4          5
C             2          4          5
D             2          4          5
E             3          5          5
F             3          3          5
G             3          3          1
A             0          1          5
E             3          5          5
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I'm suspecting the OP wants the rule to be applied to all of `COL2`, `COL3`, and `COL4`. Also, this would produce `NULL` values for `COL2`'s leading zeros... And you should remove `COL1` from the window function's `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: Yes, @LukasEder, thank you. Answer updated. And I love your `MODEL` approach even more, actually. I'm still getting into this powerful clause, don't know how to fully use it yet. :-)

Comment: I prefer your approach - keep forgetting about `LAST_VALUE`. Very cunning combo with the frame clause. [Here's some useful insight into `MODEL`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/bi-foundation/10gr1-twp-bi-dw-sqlmodel-131067.pdf). It's not really that hard, but I have to look up the syntax all the time, myself :)

Comment: @LukasEder, done removing the `col1`. This one is really subject to different interpretations of what OP wants, that's why I've put it there originally. As for the syntax lookup - the same here for all those PIVOTs and UNPIVOTs. :-)

Comment: Hah, yeah. This `COL1` - `COL4` table screams `UNPIVOT`, just because we can, right? ;)