# fill in "missing" values using match_recognize

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

[A question here, on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160574/oracle-lag-function-with-dynamic-parameter), asked for resolving a rather common use case of filling in "missing" (based on defined criteria of being missing) values with non-"missing" values from "previous" (based on defined criteria of ordering) rows.

My usual approach to this problem is to

- remap (`decode`/`case`) the "missing" values to NULLs,
- use the `last_value()` analytic function on the non-"missing"-value, with `ignore nulls` and the window of all preceding rows up to the current row in the defined ordering.

I.e., given a (taken from the original post) input set of rows `my_table` of ...

```
ORD  COL1  COL2  COL3  COL4
---  ----  ----  ----  ----
  1     A     0     1     5
  2     B     0     4     0
  3     C     2     0     0
  4     D     0     0     0
  5     E     3     5     0
  6     F     0     3     0
  7     G     0     3     1
  8     A     0     1     5
  9     E     3     5     0
```

..., an ordering of `order by ord asc`, a criterion for a value being "missing" being the value is negative or zero (`case when colX <= 0 then null else colX end` for `X` of {2,3,4}), the query of ...

```
select X.ord, X.col1,
    nvl(last_value(case when col2 > 0 then col2 end) ignore nulls over (order by ord), col2) as col2,
    nvl(last_value(case when col3 > 0 then col3 end) ignore nulls over (order by ord), col3) as col3,
    nvl(last_value(case when col4 > 0 then col4 end) ignore nulls over (order by ord), col4) as col4
from my_table X
order by ord;
```

... would yield the desired result of ...

```
ORD  COL1  COL2  COL3  COL4
---  ----  ----  ----  ----
  1     A     0     1     5
  2     B     0     4     5
  3     C     2     4     5
  4     D     2     4     5
  5     E     3     5     5
  6     F     3     3     5
  7     G     3     3     1
  8     A     3     1     5
  9     E     3     5     5
```

[Lukas Eder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/521799/lukas-eder) proposed a beautiful alternative solution with the `model` clause, working with the fact that the `model` operation in his case works [inductively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) (based on my observation of the `SQL MODEL ORDERED` operation in his query's execution plan), from the first row to the last row in the desired ordering, resulting in the row `n` having the "missing" values already filled in when the row `n+1` is being processed.

One of Lukas's comments also mentioned the possibility of using the `match_recognize` clause of Oracle 12c. My attempts to get this (completely new to me) clause understood and working failed badly. So, ...

**A bounty offer! :-)**

I'm offering a small bounty to the most elegant `match_recognize`-based solution to the above problem. All preprocessings (views, inline views, `with` clauses, ...) of the data with `pivot`, `unpivot`, self-joins, `model`, analytics, aggregations, PL/SQL, whatever, are prohibited. Only standard scalar SQL functions are allowed. I'm interested in pure `match_recognize` working on the base `my_table` data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *condition within* the pattern does get evaluated per entire row, so there has to be a condition defined for every eventuality. You can then group appropriate conditions together using the SUBSET clause.

```
WITH t(col0, col1, col2, col3, col4) AS (
  SELECT 1, 'A', 0, 1, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'B', 0, 4, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'C', 2, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'D', 0, 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'E', 3, 5, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'F', 0, 3, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 'G', 0, 3, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 'A', 0, 1, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, 'E', 3, 5, 0 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT col0, col1, C02, C03, C04
FROM t
match_recognize(
  order by col0
  measures nvl(C02.col2,0) C02,
           nvl(C03.col3,0) C03,
           nvl(C04.col4,0) C04
  all rows per match
  pattern ((C234|C23|C24|C34|C2|C3|C4|X)+)
  subset C02 = (C234, C23, C24, C2),
         C03 = (C234, C23, C34, C3),
         C04 = (C234, C24, C34, C4)
  define C234 as col2>0 and col3>0 and col4>0,
         C23 as col2>0 and col3>0,
         C24 as col2>0 and col4>0,
         C34 as col3>0 and col4>0,
         C2 as col2>0, C3 as col3>0, C4 as col4>0
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can accomplish the result using pure `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` clause. Simply because the values `col2`, `col3`, `col4` are independent on each other but the pattern is evaluated per entire row. So if multiple symbols can be matched (multiple columns have zero or non-zero values in your case) only the first one is matched as classifier and the others are ignored.

For single column there is simple solution:

```
SELECT
    ORD, COL1, COL2R COL2
FROM
    my_table
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
     ORDER BY ORD
     MEASURES
        NVL(LAST(V2.COL2), 0) AS COL2R
     ALL ROWS PER MATCH
     PATTERN ((V20*V2+V20*)+)
     DEFINE
        V2  AS  V2.COL2 > 0,
        V20 AS V20.COL2 = 0
     )
```

Anyway, analytic functions are definitely the best option in your case. Both `MODEL` and `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` clauses are meant to solve different problems where analytic functions will not help and although there are well optimized both are more heavy weight than analytic functions.

Comment: I know the two are more _heavyweight_. It does not matter, though. I'm interested in a "show off" of the `match_recognize` capabilities; not interested in being told what shall I use and what not for a particular problem. :-) I simply like to know well the options I have. Consider my question being academic.

Comment: Anyway, so far, your answer agrees with what I understood about the `match_recognize`... That the pattern gets evaluated per entire row. That was the "failed badly" part I was speaking of. Still, there are more experienced people than I out there, so...